# Sequence labels with prior knowledge about valid labels

Tags: neural-network, text-classification

I am working on a text classification problem where on inference, there is a known set of valid classifications which is smaller than the set of all possible labels.

> **Example**: There are 5 labels: L1, L2, ..., L5
>
> On inference, the user wants to classify text T1, but we have prior
> knowledge that T1 can only have labels L2, L3, or L4. In another case,
> we want to classify T2 with prior knowledge that T2 can only have
> labels L1, and L2

Do I have to train a separate model / filter results for each combination of applicable labels or is there a way to use one model that can take in the labelset and output the likelihood for only the valid labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> train a separate model ... for each combination of applicable labels

You are getting at model performance.
You don't *have* to do anything, but if you
train different kinds of models,
that is, models drawn from distinct hypothesis sets,
you may observe various performance levels.

It sounds like you have an existing model
that outputs five raw scores.
And then you incorporate "extra" knowledge,
which the model is ignorant of,
to zero out some scores before
scaling them into probabilities
and choosing argmax maximum likelihood.

Training many models is certainly one possible refinement,
but augmenting the width of the input training vector is another.
One obvious augmentation is to tack on five indicator
variables, saying that each one-hot encoded label
is {allowed, disallowed}.
Logistic regression, decision tree, and other modeling techniques
will learn from such hints.

But perhaps the business constraint comes from something
simpler, like stage within the customer journey.
If you have labels like {prospect, initial customer,
repeat customer} which induce {allowed, disallowed}
over the labels, consider one-hot encoding *those*
instead, to reduce the model complexity.

No matter which approach you choose,
or how much of the SME's business rules
you make available during training,
you can *always* post-filter, there's nothing
wrong with that. And simple filters can
be implemented very quickly, without the
cost of retraining a model to learn new
business rules.

tl;dr: If you can expose Bayesian priors
at training time, do so, expose as much
signal within the noise as feasible.

Comment: Ah thank you! I didn't think about one hot encoding the intermediate stages like you mentioned. I'll try that and the filtering option